# Bootstrap datatables -Data Exporting Issues

Tags: datatables, tabletools

I am using bootstrap datatables with an export tool extension which works great . The only issue is that i have individual column filter dropdowns at the footer of the table, due to which the column filters at the bottom are also included in the exported PDF/CSV .

Below is how my datatable is initialized :

```js
    var table = $('#example').DataTable(
                    {
                "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                "tableTools": {
                    "oFeatures": {
            "bCsv": false,
            "bXls": false,
            "bCopy": false,
            "bPrint": false
        },

                    "sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": [
                {'sExtends':'pdf',
                  "oSelectorOpts": { filter: 'applied', order: 'current' },
                }
                {'sExtends':'print',
                  "oSelectorOpts": { filter: 'applied', order: 'current' },
                }
              ]
                }
            }
                    );


$("#example tfoot th").each( function ( i ) {
            var title = $('#example thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
            if(title!=='Date of Upload' && title!=='Action'){
        var select = $('<select style="width:100%"><option value="">Select '+title+'</option></select>')
            .appendTo( $(this).empty() )
            .on( 'change', function () {
                var val = $(this).val();

                table.column( i )
                    .search( val ? '^'+$(this).val()+'$' : val, true, false )
                    .draw();
            } );

        table.column( i ).data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
            select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
        } );
            }
    } );
```

Please let me know if there is a way to resolve this issue .

Comment: Looks like there is no 'Expert' in Stackoverflow who can resolve this issue.No one even bothers to view it looking at the Heading of the issue .lolz

Comment: I believe that your choice of tags caused the vague attention to the question. `PHP` is really not in focus here, and the `bootstrap` tag should never be used in this context -> "_Not to be confused with Twitter's Bootstrap CSS framework; please use the twitter-bootstrap tag.._" Furthermore, jQuery dataTables has nothing to do with twitter bootstrap itself, dataTables just facilitate twitter bootstraps CSS structure.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple option for this, [bFooter](https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/button_options#bFooter). `bFooter` defines whether you want the footer to be included in the export or not. Example :

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    //... other initialisation options
    tableTools: {
        sSwfPath: "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"",
        aButtons: [
            { sExtends :'pdf',
              oSelectorOpts: { filter: 'applied', order: 'current' },
              bFooter: false //<-- add this to each button declaration
            }
            //... more buttons
       ]
    }
})
```

Comment: @user1411837, so - did it work? You seemed really eager for a fast answer, two days ago...

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to reply to @davidkonrad, but his solution worked for me too. Thank you.

Here is my code for reference, with ColVis (column hiding), TableTools (export to csv,pdf), and ColReorder (change order of tables). Everything works great except that the column reorders aren't reflected in the export, but I'm sure it's possible. Be aware that the code format has messed up some of my indenting.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#content').DataTable( {
    dom: 'TC<"clear">Rlfrtip',
    "oTableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "/configs/DataTables-1.10.5/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
        "aButtons": [
            {'sExtends':'copy',
                "oSelectorOpts": { filter: 'applied', order: 'current' },
                "mColumns": "visible",
                "bFooter": false
            },
            {'sExtends':'print',
                "oSelectorOpts": { filter: 'applied', order: 'current' },
                "mColumns": "visible",
                "bFooter": false,
            },
            {'sExtends':'csv',
                "oSelectorOpts": { filter: 'applied', order: 'current' },
                "mColumns": "visible",
                "bFooter": false,
            },
            {'sExtends':'pdf',
                "oSelectorOpts": { filter: 'applied', order: 'current' },
                "mColumns": "visible",
                "bFooter": false,
            }
        ]
    },
    initComplete: function () {
        var api = this.api();

        api.columns().indexes().flatten().each( function ( i ) {
            var column = api.column( i );
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );

            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
    }
});
} );
```